# Angular Syncfusion pivotview internationalization doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to set the text of the pivot view and the pivot field list to spanish, but it simply doesn't work.
I tried it with, L10n.load in globals, also tried in ngOnInit, also I tried importing a json file.

=======Here starts First try========

repo-pivote.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation,ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
    FieldListService, CalculatedFieldService,PivotView,
    ToolbarService, ConditionalFormattingService, ToolbarItems, DisplayOption, GroupingBarService,IDataOptions
} from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-pivotview';
import { GridSettings } from '@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/pivotview/model/gridsettings';
import { L10n} from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import { ChartSettings } from '@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/pivotview/model/chartsettings';
import {RepoCostosService} from './repo-costos.service';

L10n.load({
       es: {
           pivotview: {
               grandTotal: 'TOTAL',
               total: 'Total',
               value: 'Valor',
               noValue: 'Sin Valor',
               row: 'Fila',
               column: 'Columna',
               collapse: 'Colapsar',
               expand: 'Expandir'
           },
           pivotfieldlist: {
               fieldList: 'Lista de Campos',
               dropRowPrompt: 'Suelte Fila Aquí',
               dropColPrompt: 'Suelte Columna Aquí',
               dropValPrompt: 'Suelte Valor Aquí',
               dropFilterPrompt: 'Suelte Filtro Aquí',
               addPrompt: 'Solicitar',
               centerHeader: 'Mostrar el Encabezado Centrado:',
               add: 'Agregar',
               drag: 'Arrastrar',
               filters: 'Filtros',
               rows: 'Filas',
               columns: 'Columnas',
               values: 'Valores',
               error: 'Error',
               dropAction: 'Soltar en esta zona',
               search: 'Buscar',
               close: 'Cerrar',
               cancel: 'Cancelar',
               delete: 'Borrar',
               alert: 'Advertencia',
               warning: 'Precaución',
               ok: 'OK',
               allFields: 'Todos los Campos',
               noMatches: 'Sin coincidencias'
           }
       }
   });

@Component({
  selector: 'app-repo-pivote',
  template:`<body class="with-side-menu control-panel control-panel-compact">
<app-menu-costos></app-menu-costos>
    <div class="page-content mb-5">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-12">
                        <section class="card card-blue-fill">
                        <header class="card-header text-center">
                            <h3>Reporte de Costos Dinámico</h3>
                        </header>
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <div class="row mt-3" >
                  <div class="col-xl-12">
                                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline" title="Generar Reporte" (click)="btnTabClick();" *ngIf="conPermiso(1250,false)"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>-->
                                        </div>

                    <div class="card-block">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="control-section" id="pivot-table-section">
                            <div>
                                <ejs-pivotview #pivotview id='PivotView' [dataSourceSettings]=dataSourceSettings allowExcelExport='true'
                                    allowConditionalFormatting='false' allowPdfExport='true' showToolbar='true' allowCalculatedField='true'
                                    showFieldList='true' showGroupingBar='true' width='100%' [chartSettings]='chartSettings'
                                     height='500' [gridSettings]='gridSettings' locale='es' [toolbar]='toolbarOptions' enableVirtualization='true'>
                                </ejs-pivotview>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

                      </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div><!--.container-fluid-->
    </div><!--.page-content-->

</body>`,
  styleUrls: ['./repo-pivote.component.css'],
  providers: [CalculatedFieldService, ToolbarService, ConditionalFormattingService, FieldListService, GroupingBarService]
})
export class RepoPivoteComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {

 @ViewChild('pivotview',{static: false}) pivotTableObj: PivotView;

  public toolbarOptions: ToolbarItems[];
  public chartSettings: ChartSettings;
  public displayOption: DisplayOption;

    public dataSourceSettings: IDataOptions;
    public gridSettings: GridSettings;


    datos:any[];

    constructor(private repocost:RepoCostosService){
    }

    ngAfterViewInit():void {
      console.log(this.pivotTableObj);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.gridSettings = {
            columnWidth: 140
        } as GridSettings;

        this.toolbarOptions = ['Export', 'SubTotal', 'GrandTotal', 'FieldList'] as ToolbarItems[];

        this.repocost.jsonRepo(-1,-1,-1,"xlsx")
          .subscribe((respuesta:any) => {
            this.datos = respuesta;
            console.log(respuesta);
              this.dataSourceSettings = {
                    enableSorting: true,
                    columns: [{ name: 'iniPeriodo'  }],
                    values: [{ name: 'monto', caption: 'Costos', type:'Max' }, {name: 'montoDolares', caption: 'Costos($)', type:'Max'}],
                    dataSource: this.datos,
                    rows: [{ name: 'descripcionOrigen' }],
                    formatSettings: [{ name: 'monto', format: '₡#,##0.00' },{ name: 'montoDolares', format: '$#,##0.00' },{name:'iniPeriodo', type:'date', format:'dd/MM/yyyy'},{name:'finPeriodo', type:'date', format:'dd/MM/yyyy'}],
                    expandAll: false,
                    filters: []
                };
                console.log(this.pivotTableObj);

            });
      }
}
```

==== First Try Ends Here

Now Second try

==== Second try starts here

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation,ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
    FieldListService, CalculatedFieldService,PivotView,
    ToolbarService, ConditionalFormattingService, ToolbarItems, DisplayOption, GroupingBarService,IDataOptions
} from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-pivotview';
import { GridSettings } from '@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/pivotview/model/gridsettings';
import { L10n} from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import { ChartSettings } from '@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/pivotview/model/chartsettings';
import {RepoCostosService} from './repo-costos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-repo-pivote',
  template:`<body class="with-side-menu control-panel control-panel-compact">
<app-menu-costos></app-menu-costos>
    <div class="page-content mb-5">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-12">
                        <section class="card card-blue-fill">
                        <header class="card-header text-center">
                            <h3>Reporte de Costos Dinámico</h3>
                        </header>
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <div class="row mt-3" >
                  <div class="col-xl-12">
                                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline" title="Generar Reporte" (click)="btnTabClick();" *ngIf="conPermiso(1250,false)"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>-->
                                        </div>

                    <div class="card-block">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="control-section" id="pivot-table-section">
                            <div>
                                <ejs-pivotview #pivotview id='PivotView' [dataSourceSettings]=dataSourceSettings allowExcelExport='true'
                                    allowConditionalFormatting='false' allowPdfExport='true' showToolbar='true' allowCalculatedField='true'
                                    showFieldList='true' showGroupingBar='true' width='100%' [chartSettings]='chartSettings'
                                     height='500' [gridSettings]='gridSettings' locale='es' [toolbar]='toolbarOptions' enableVirtualization='true'>
                                </ejs-pivotview>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

                      </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div><!--.container-fluid-->
    </div><!--.page-content-->

</body>`,
  styleUrls: ['./repo-pivote.component.css'],
  providers: [CalculatedFieldService, ToolbarService, ConditionalFormattingService, FieldListService, GroupingBarService]
})
export class RepoPivoteComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {

 @ViewChild('pivotview',{static: false}) pivotTableObj: PivotView;

  public toolbarOptions: ToolbarItems[];
  public chartSettings: ChartSettings;
  public displayOption: DisplayOption;

    public dataSourceSettings: IDataOptions;
    public gridSettings: GridSettings;


    datos:any[];

    constructor(private repocost:RepoCostosService){
    }

    ngAfterViewInit():void {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      L10n.load({
             es: {
                 pivotview: {
                     grandTotal: 'TOTAL',
                     total: 'Total',
                     value: 'Valor',
                     noValue: 'Sin Valor',
                     row: 'Fila',
                     column: 'Columna',
                     collapse: 'Colapsar',
                     expand: 'Expandir'
                 },
                 pivotfieldlist: {
                     fieldList: 'Lista de Campos',
                     dropRowPrompt: 'Suelte Fila Aquí',
                     dropColPrompt: 'Suelte Columna Aquí',
                     dropValPrompt: 'Suelte Valor Aquí',
                     dropFilterPrompt: 'Suelte Filtro Aquí',
                     addPrompt: 'Solicitar',
                     centerHeader: 'Mostrar el Encabezado Centrado:',
                     add: 'Agregar',
                     drag: 'Arrastrar',
                     filters: 'Filtros',
                     rows: 'Filas',
                     columns: 'Columnas',
                     values: 'Valores',
                     error: 'Error',
                     dropAction: 'Soltar en esta zona',
                     search: 'Buscar',
                     close: 'Cerrar',
                     cancel: 'Cancelar',
                     delete: 'Borrar',
                     alert: 'Advertencia',
                     warning: 'Precaución',
                     ok: 'OK',
                     allFields: 'Todos los Campos',
                     noMatches: 'Sin coincidencias'
                 }
             }
         });


        this.gridSettings = {
            columnWidth: 140
        } as GridSettings;

        this.toolbarOptions = ['Export', 'SubTotal', 'GrandTotal', 'FieldList'] as ToolbarItems[];

        this.repocost.jsonRepo(-1,-1,-1,"xlsx")
          .subscribe((respuesta:any) => {
            this.datos = respuesta;
            console.log(respuesta);
              this.dataSourceSettings = {
                    enableSorting: true,
                    columns: [{ name: 'iniPeriodo'  }],
                    values: [{ name: 'monto', caption: 'Costos', type:'Max' }, {name: 'montoDolares', caption: 'Costos($)', type:'Max'}],
                    dataSource: this.datos,
                    rows: [{ name: 'descripcionOrigen' }],
                    formatSettings: [{ name: 'monto', format: '₡#,##0.00' },{ name: 'montoDolares', format: '$#,##0.00' },{name:'iniPeriodo', type:'date', format:'dd/MM/yyyy'},{name:'finPeriodo', type:'date', format:'dd/MM/yyyy'}],
                    expandAll: false,
                    filters: []
                };
                console.log(this.pivotTableObj);
            });
      }
}
```

==== End of Second try

===== Third try starts Here

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation,ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
    FieldListService, CalculatedFieldService,PivotView,
    ToolbarService, ConditionalFormattingService, ToolbarItems, DisplayOption, GroupingBarService,IDataOptions
} from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-pivotview';
import { GridSettings } from '@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/pivotview/model/gridsettings';
import { L10n} from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import { ChartSettings } from '@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/pivotview/model/chartsettings';
import {RepoCostosService} from './repo-costos.service';
import espanol from '../../../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-locale/es.json';

L10n.load({es: espanol.es});

@Component({
  selector: 'app-repo-pivote',
  template:`<body class="with-side-menu control-panel control-panel-compact">
<app-menu-costos></app-menu-costos>
    <div class="page-content mb-5">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-12">
                        <section class="card card-blue-fill">
                        <header class="card-header text-center">
                            <h3>Reporte de Costos Dinámico</h3>
                        </header>
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <div class="row mt-3" >
                  <div class="col-xl-12">
                                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline" title="Generar Reporte" (click)="btnTabClick();" *ngIf="conPermiso(1250,false)"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>-->
                                        </div>

                    <div class="card-block">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="control-section" id="pivot-table-section">
                            <div>
                                <ejs-pivotview #pivotview id='PivotView' [dataSourceSettings]=dataSourceSettings allowExcelExport='true'
                                    allowConditionalFormatting='false' allowPdfExport='true' showToolbar='true' allowCalculatedField='true'
                                    showFieldList='true' showGroupingBar='true' width='100%' [chartSettings]='chartSettings'
                                     height='500' [gridSettings]='gridSettings' locale='es' [toolbar]='toolbarOptions' enableVirtualization='true'>
                                </ejs-pivotview>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

                      </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div><!--.container-fluid-->
    </div><!--.page-content-->

</body>`,
  styleUrls: ['./repo-pivote.component.css'],
  providers: [CalculatedFieldService, ToolbarService, ConditionalFormattingService, FieldListService, GroupingBarService]
})
export class RepoPivoteComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {

 @ViewChild('pivotview',{static: false}) pivotTableObj: PivotView;

  public toolbarOptions: ToolbarItems[];
  public chartSettings: ChartSettings;
  public displayOption: DisplayOption;

    public dataSourceSettings: IDataOptions;
    public gridSettings: GridSettings;


    datos:any[];

    constructor(private repocost:RepoCostosService){
    }

    ngAfterViewInit():void {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.gridSettings = {
            columnWidth: 140
        } as GridSettings;

        this.toolbarOptions = ['Export', 'SubTotal', 'GrandTotal', 'FieldList'] as ToolbarItems[];

        this.repocost.jsonRepo(-1,-1,-1,"xlsx")
          .subscribe((respuesta:any) => {
            this.datos = respuesta;
            console.log(respuesta);
              this.dataSourceSettings = {
                    enableSorting: true,
                    columns: [{ name: 'iniPeriodo'  }],
                    values: [{ name: 'monto', caption: 'Costos', type:'Max' }, {name: 'montoDolares', caption: 'Costos($)', type:'Max'}],
                    dataSource: this.datos,
                    rows: [{ name: 'descripcionOrigen' }],
                    formatSettings: [{ name: 'monto', format: '₡#,##0.00' },{ name: 'montoDolares', format: '$#,##0.00' },{name:'iniPeriodo', type:'date', format:'dd/MM/yyyy'},{name:'finPeriodo', type:'date', format:'dd/MM/yyyy'}],
                    expandAll: false,
                    filters: []
                };
            });
      }
}
```

==== Third try ends here

The fourth try is the same of the third try, but L10n.load instead of global declaration is in ngOnInit function.

The json file of the third and fourth try is here

https://github.com/syncfusion/ej2-locale/blob/master/src/es.json

For this I made the tsconfig.* modifications.

Everything is working fine but internationalization, all the texts remains in English,  after all of these. I have no problems with english, but the client doesn't.

I don't know what else i can do.

Comment: Did you find out solution or not ? and can you share data-source object file too.

Comment: Not yet. Datasource comes from rest api            .subscribe((respuesta:any) => {
            this.datos = respuesta;
            console.log(respuesta);
              this.dataSourceSettings = {
            ...     dataSource: this.datos,

Comment: setCulture('es-ES') use this in your first attempt code before L10n.load and change 
           L10n.load({
       'es-ES': {
           AND rest will be same try this change and see the results

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the results are the same here.

Comment: I can't run it, it says Import error, can't find file:
../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-locale/src/es.json. But thanks for all your help, I really aprecciate it.

Comment: Now updated above link and working it right, see if that works for you

Comment: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/pivotview/globalization-and-localization/#globalization here is reference document

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239813/discussion-between-alejandro-vargas-and-grd).

Comment: Will you please help by supporting https://www.buymeacoffee.com/grdtech I am also looking for work in angular. Thank you @AlejandroVargas